# Calculation based on 2 fact tables (plan/actual comparison)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, summarize, star-schema

I have to link TWO tables (Planning vs Executed) that have: date, shift, SKU and Quantity to calculate the match between planned and executed (in %).
In other words, I need to create a comparison  of two tables using 3 fields as reference (Date, Shift, SKU) and the comparison will use Programmed vs Executed production.

The tables I have are like these:

***Planning Table***

| DateProg | Shift | SKU | QtyProg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | ABC | 12 |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | ABC | 24 |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | JKL | 35 |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | JKL | 20 |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | ABC | 15 |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | ABC | 15 |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | JKL | 33 |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | JKL | 22 |

***Production Table***

| DateProduction | Shift | SKU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | ABC |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | ABC |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | JKL |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | JKL |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | JKL |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | JKL |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | JKL |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | ABC |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | ABC |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | JKL |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | JKL |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | JKL |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | JKL |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | ABC |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | JKL |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | JKL |

For this sample data, my end result must be like this

| DateProg | SHIFT | SKU | QtyProg | QtyExecuted | %Adherency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | ABC | 12 | 2 | =2/12 |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | ABC | 24 | 2 | =2/24 |
| 2022/12/01 | 1 | JKL | 35 | 4 | =4/35 |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | JKL | 20 | 2 | =2/20 |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | ABC | 15 | 0 | =0 |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | ABC | 15 | 1 | =1/15 |
| 2022/12/02 | 1 | JKL | 33 | 3 | =3/33 |
| 2022/12/02 | 2 | JKL | 22 | 2 | =2/22 |

I think it will take some steps to solve the complete problem.
But I will appreciate any help.

I tried to use DAX in a number of different ways. And up to now, none of a good result.

Comment: Hi,guys. I appreciate help formatting the tables (I promise improve over time). 

About the problem, I solved the problem. 
The steps I made: 
FIRST - I summarized the production table using Summarize(DateProduction, SKU, Shift, Count(SKU)) 
SECOND - I made Planned table to have the same columns and order that the summarized production
THIRD - I set NO relationships between the 2 tables
FOURTH - I created the final table_Adherency by using SelectColumns for each table and a NaturalLetfOuterJoin to make the table of interest
FIFTH - I created a measure to %Adherency
It worked!

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. You can post your answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I understand that every row in the Production Table stands for 1 Qty executed, so add a column

```
QtyExecuted  = 1
```

2. Add a Key column to the Production Table

```
Key = 'Production Table'[DateProduction] & 'Production Table'[SKU] & 'Production Table'[Shift]
```

3. Add a similar Key column to the Planning Table

```
Key = 'Planning Table'[DateProg] & 'Planning Table'[SKU] & 'Planning Table'[Shift]
```

4. Create a one-to-many relationship between `'Planning Table'[Key]` and `'Production Table'[Key]`
5. Add QtyExecuted to the Planning Table

```
QtyExecuted = SUMX(RELATEDTABLE('Production Table'), 'Production Table'[QtyExecuted])
```

6. Add %Adherency to the Planning Table

```
% Adherency = DIVIDE('Planning Table'[QtyExecuted], 'Planning Table'[QtyProg])
```

The resulting table should look like this:

[image]

Note that your expected data is wrong with regards to the JKL production on 2022/12/01.

Comment: Thanks for helpimg, Peter. I've tried here and worked perfetctly.

Comment: Hi @Peter. I've found an issue using this solution. 

I always get the production planned when the production executed is equal to 0. But I cannot see when the production executed is > 0 and planned = 0. 

That happens, for example, when part of a planned production is delayed to the next shift. 
I appreciate any help.